# modulo in assembly

Tags: c, assembly, modulo

I've been trying for over 3 hours to figure out what's wrong with the next program.
All I'm trying to do is to divide x in y, and then print the result of the division and the modulo.
Also, the printf of the modulo, with the % inside, messes all up. Does anyone know how to fix that?
I'm working on assembly IA32. Assume I get x and y from the user already.

```
.section    .rodata
format1:    .string "Div : %d / %d = %d\n"
format2:    .string "Mod : %d % %d = %d\n"

    .text
.globl  main    
    .type   main, @function 

# operation divide
movl    x,  %eax
cltd
idivl   y
pushl   %eax
pushl   y
pushl   x
pushl   $format1
call    printf

# operation modulo
pushl   %edx
pushl   y
pushl   x
pushl   $format2
call    printf
```

I know the modulo should be kept in the %edx register, so why it doesnt work?
Thanks alot! D:

edit:
Ok, so I saved %edx in %ebx and now the modulo works fine. (if I print what's in %edx it gives the right modulo) 
But the print to the screen still not what I want. This is the output for x=2, y=4:

```
Divide : 2 / 4 = 0
Modulo : 2 %d = 4
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
Divide : 2 / 4 = 0.50
Modulo : 2 % 4 = 2
```

Comment: maybe printf is changing the contents of the register

Comment: I dont think so, ive tried other operands such as multiply and it worked fine

Comment: What's the input, the current output, and the expected output?

Comment: You're not clearing your stack and you're not saving your registers before the call to printf.

Answer (score 2):

EAX, ECX and EDX are caller saved registers, this means **you** must save them before calling `printf`, which is at liberty to change any of those registers without restoring them.

EBX, ESI and EDI on the other hand are callee-saved, which means every function needs to restore them to their original contents before the call.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [System V ABI for Intel386](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/abi386-4.pdf), functions are allowed to use `%ecx` and `%edx` as scratch registers and callees don't have to preserve their value for the caller. This means, that `printf` is allowed to overwrite the value of `%edx`, thus destroying the value of the reminer. You could save it by transfering the value of `%edx` to `%esi` or `%edi`, as per the specification their value has to be preserved by the callees (they "belong" to the caller).

This said, you have an error in `format2`. You should change it to:

```
format2:    .string "Mod : %d %% %d = %d\n"
```

Literal `%` must be written as `%%` in the format string, otherwise it will be iterpreted as a format specifier by `printf`.